# aws ecr No scan findings Scan status: UNSUPPORTED_IMAGE

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hellow. When aws ecr scan image I got this error
**No scan findings
Scan status: UNSUPPORTED_IMAGE**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*docker build --no-cache -t test-4 .*

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat libtool autoconf automake g++ gcc zlib zlib-dev make nasm curl
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /var/www/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn run cache & \&& yarn build

FROM node:14-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat libtool autoconf automake g++ gcc zlib zlib-dev make nasm curl

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/next-i18next.config.js ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/sp-push-worker-fb.js ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/cache.js ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/docker-entrypoint.sh ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/public ./public
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/.next ./.next
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/.env ./.env
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/sentry.client.config.js ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/sentry.server.config.js ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /var/www/sentry.properties ./

#COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I use advanced scan for images

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.